# How to Install pushbullet indicator on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

can't install **pushbullet indicator** on Ubuntu 16.04.

(I'm using ppa:atareao/atareao)

**I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)with nemo**

Comment: The package name is `nautilus-pushbullet`, did you try that? `sudo apt-get install nautilus-pushbullet`

Comment: I'm  using nemo-pushbullet and pushbullet indicator is missing

Comment: Your question states `Ubuntu 16.04` this imply standard Ubuntu, what is your actual distribution? Please update you question with as much information as possible, as it stands this is very unclear.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)with nemo

Comment: There is no package on that PPA released for `pushbullet-indicator` for 16.04, it simply has not yet been released. You should contact the maintainer of the PPA and ask for an ETA https://launchpad.net/~lorenzo-carbonell

Comment: thanks for the answer
i will send a message to the maintainer of  ppa:atareao/atareao

Comment: I looked around and this seems the only place to get that package, they update the PPA a lot, so hopefully it won't take them long.

Comment: looking for the same ! did anyone get news?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a package for Xenial in the repository now:

https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao/+packages

Answer (score 3):

Still no `pushbullet-indicator` supported for Xenial Xerus in `ppa:atareao/atareao`. Contacted the maintainer, the response indicated a different PPA should be used: `ppa:atareao/pushbullet`

https://blueprints.launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/pushbullet

Confirmed this is working by successfully installing `pushbullet-indicator` on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/pushbullet
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pushbullet-indicator
```

[link](https://www.atareao.es/apps/pushbullet-indicator-para-enviar-archivos-entre-ubuntu-y-android/)

Comment: The problem is that there is no package for pushbullet-indicator for Ubuntu 16.04 in that PPA, only pushbullet-indicator packages .

Comment: @insign: The `pushbullet` packages in the `atareo` PPA have smaller version numbers than in the dedicated `pushbullet` PPA (although they are newer). I'm reverting your changes.